# Output sum, avg, and standard deviation from imported text file arrays

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

my text file, garbageData contains these numbers:

40 50 43 98 20

10 67 84 25 71

37 54 32 90 62

76 49 69 95 44

11 22 33 44 55

I'm trying to read garbageData and store the numbers in an array. Then I need to get a sum, average, and standard deviation of those numbers that are stored.

Then for each number in the array, I need to add a random number ranging from 1 to 10 to that number and store the new number in a different array.

This is what I have so far, but I can't manipulate it. What am I doing wrong?

```
    with open('garbageData.txt','r') as myArray:
       for x in myArray:
       sum = sum(myArray)   
       print(sum)
```

Comment: `myArray` is a list of strings, not numbers.

Comment: Look into [` numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) then run those aggregates.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a file returns strings, it doesn't parse the numbers. You need to split the file and convert them to numbers.

```
with open('garbageData.txt', 'r') as f:
    nums = [int(x) for x in f.read().split()]
mysum = sum(nums)
print(mysum)
```

You shouldn't use `sum` as your variable name, since it will replace the built-in function `sum()`.

Comment: what is the syntax for taking the average?

Comment: `avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)`

Comment: Isn't that just high school math?

Comment: I just started using Python last week, so I wasn't sure what I could use. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: For standard deviation see [stdev](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev)